# Disable rightclick on Zeppelin notebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, apache-zeppelin, spark-notebook

I am using Zeppelin 0.6.0 notebooks on my dashboard.

I am embedding notebooks in an iframe, a simple HTML page.

I want to disable the right click on my dashboard.

I can disable right click outside the iframe area, but I cannot disable it inside the iframe area.

I tried with all possible code available on Google like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var iframeEl = $('#iframe1').contents().get(0);
  $(iframeEl).bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
});

onload="disableContextMenu();" oncontextmenu="return false"
```

etc...

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<body style="text-align:center;position:relative;">
  <div id='testing'>
    <h3 align='center'>Karnataka</h3>
    <iframe src="http://my_ip_Address:8080/#/notebook/2BTQV69P2/paragraph/20160829-125413_974103599?asIframe" width="1200" height="550"  scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" id="iframe1" style="text-align:center;pointer-events:none;" >Browser not compatible.</iframe>
    <div id="karnataka"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I disable right click on the Notebook?

As I read it:

> "It is possible if the page inside an iframe is on the same domain. While if you access the page of a different domain inside an iframe, then it is not recommended."

Anyone came across this scenario and found any solutions?

Other than iframe how can I embed it in my dashboard?